# Governing equations vs Transport equations

Tags: differential-equations, navier-stokes

I posted it in computational-science SE site, and it was suggested I shift it here. This is a basic question. But I did not find any explanations for this. How are governing equations, like mass, momentum, energy conservations equations, different from 'Transport equation'?. Is a conservation equation, like energy equation (heat equation), a transport equation for the temperature?

Comment: generally they are used as synonyms